# Most efficient way to prep data for pytorch lstm from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pytorch

I am trying to feed data into my lstm. I have the data across multiple csv's, so I created a generator to load it in. However, I am having some issues on prepping the data for my lstm.

I understand this code (I got it from the pytorch docs)

```py
seq_len = 5
batch_size= 3
cols_num = 10
hidden_size=20
num_layers = 2

rnn = nn.LSTM(input_size=cols_num, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers)

data = torch.randn(seq_len, batch_size, cols_num)
h0 = torch.randn(batch_size, seq_len, hidden_size)
c0 = torch.randn(batch_size, seq_len, hidden_size)
output, (hn, cn) = rnn(data)
```

However, I think my disconnect is with using actual data not the torch.randn().

This is my current generator:

```py
def data_loader(batch_size, fp, dropcol, seq_len):
    while True:
        for f in fp:
            gc.collect()
            df=pd.read_csv(f)
            df=df.replace(np.nan, 0)
            df=df.drop(dropcol,1)
            df['minute'] = df['minute'].apply(lambda x: min_idx(x))
            row_count, col_count = df.shape
            encoder_input = []
            prev = 0
            for idx, b in enumerate(range(1, row_count)):
                end = prev + batch_size
                window = df.iloc[prev:end]
                prev = end - 1
                w = np.array(window, dtype='float64')
                if w.shape[0] != batch_size:  break
                encoder_input.append(w)
                if idx == seq_len:
                    w0 = encoder_input
                    encoder_input = []
                    yield w0
```

but I get errors when I run this:

```py
loader = data_loader(batch_size=batch_size, fp=<list of csvs>, dropcol=idcol, seq_len=2)
lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, batch_first=batch_first)


for batch in loader:
    b = torch.tensor(batch)
    output, hidden = lstm(b)
```

The error: 
`RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #4 'mat1'`

What is the error in how I am thinking? Also, how should I format an h0 or c0 from the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in how you are thinking, the error is in how Pytorch models accept input. The default data type created in a Pytorch tensor is `torch.float64`
where the default (and possibly only) data type accepted by models is `torch.float32`.

To fix this use:

```
b = torch.tensor(batch, dtype=torch.float32)
```

This will convert your inputs to `torch.float32`.

Comment: Why does torch even support float64 then?

Comment: @Kajymo My guess is for tensors used in models, not inputs.